# Why Jsoup does not report error when it encounters missing tags?

Tags: java, jsoup

I understand that Jsoup behavior is to try to [do the best by adding missing tag or removing existing tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931799/jsoup-behavior-when-any-html-end-tag-is-missing). It still should be reported in the error parser list though. Below is my sample code.

```
final String test = "<img /><noscript><a href=\"http://www.google.com\">google</a>";
Parser parser = Parser.htmlParser();
parser.setTrackErrors(10);
Document document = parser.parseInput(test, StringUtils.EMPTY);
System.out.println("BEFORE: " + test);
System.out.println("JSPARSED: " + StringUtils.remove(document.body().html(), "\n"));
System.out.println("Tracking errors: " + parser.isTrackErrors());
System.out.println("Number of errors: " + parser.getErrors().size());
```

This gives me:

```
ORIGINAL: <img /><noscript><a href="http://www.google.com">google</a>
JSPARSED: <img /><noscript> <a href="http://www.google.com">google</a></noscript>
Tracking errors: true
Number of errors: 0
```

Note that Jsoup inserted a new nonscript enclosing tag but did not report the problem in the error list. I'm using Jsoup 1.7.3. Any idea why it is doing that? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a bug.

It is following the standard as it does the browsers when parse **invalid HTML with unclosed tags**.

It was a bug in the version 1.7.2 which was fixed in the version 1.7.3

U can check it here:

Report of the bug in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813821/jsoup-parsing-invalid-html-with-unclosed-tags)

Report of the bug in [github](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/313)